# Select count(*) and select sum(my_data) after insert- error syntax#1064

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am a beginner in sql, and even in programming, recently I discovered the triggers, and I want to calculate the maximum number of active lines, and the total sum of active weights
ps: active records are defined with 'cancled = 0'
I had error # 1064 near the line where I declared my variable (row 2)

i am running this into PHPMYADMIN (MySQL) triggers.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @max_rows int;
DECLARE @max_tare int;
SET @max_rows = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM history WHERE cancled = 0;
SET @max_tare= SELECT SUM(tare) FROM history WHERE cancled = 0;
UPDATE max_tare
SET max_row  = @max_rows,
    max_tare = @max_tare
WHERE id = 1
END
```

I was expecting that I updated line 1 with the max number of rows and the total sum of active weights but I have an error

> MySQL replied: # 1064 - Syntax error near '@max_rows int; DECLARE
>   @max_tare int; SET @max_rows = SELECT COUNT (*) FROM his' at line 2

after Paul comment  i changed the code to this :

```
BEGIN
DECLARE max_r int;
DECLARE max_t int;
SET max_r = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM history WHERE cancled = 0;
SET max_t = SELECT SUM(tare) FROM history WHERE cancled = 0;
UPDATE max_tare
SET max_row  = max_r,
    max_tare = max_t
WHERE id = 1
END
```

this is the new error :

> MySQL replied: # 1064 - Syntax error near SELECT COUNT (*) FROM
>   history WHERE cancled = 0; SET max_t = SELECT SUM (tare) FR 'at line 4

ty in advance.

Comment: You don't need to `DECLARE` user variables (such that begin with `@`). Remove the `DECLARE` lines.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i did it now it said  error1064 in line 4

Comment: Surround the select statements with parentheses `(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM history WHERE cancled = 0)`

Comment: @forpas it  worked fine  ty  i hae  to make this as solved now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @paul Spiegel and @forpas for helping 
this code helped solved the problem

```
IF(NEW.mix != '') THEN
UPDATE max_tare
SET max_row  = (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM history WHERE nom LIKE NEW.mix),
    max_tare = (SELECT SUM(tare) FROM history WHERE cancled = 0)
WHERE id = 1;
ELSE
UPDATE max_tare
SET max_row  = (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM history WHERE cancled = 0),
    max_tare = (SELECT SUM(tare) FROM history WHERE cancled = 0)
WHERE id = 1;
END IF;
END
```

this worked fine for me, thanks guys